# Clone a DOM element with ng-click in AngularJS markup without scope function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

Is it possible to clone an DOM element in AngularJS when clicked on it without using a custom function defined in controller/scope?

Example:

```
<div>
  <div ng-click="create copy of this">some content</div>
</div>
```

becomes:

```
<div>
  <div ng-click="create copy of this">some content</div>
  <div ng-click="create copy of this">some content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `ng-click` always calls functions in the scope. You could create a directive if you wanted to.

Comment: And Expressions like `ng-click="variable=4"`, too.